# What does the xpath expression "@*" mean?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Microsoft's XSLT template on Visual Studio has something like:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
```

What is **@***?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@*` is short for `attribute::*` and selects all attributes of the context node (or, in an XSLT match pattern, it's more appropriate to say that it *matches* all attributes). From [the XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

> There is also an abbreviation for attributes: `attribute::` can be
>   abbreviated to `@`. For example, a location path
>   `para[@type="warning"]` is short for
>   `child::para[attribute::type="warning"]` and so selects `para`
>   children with a `type` attribute with value equal to `warning`.

Comment: Yep! Deleting my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

That means match any attribute.

http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN - [XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx):

> @* | All attributes of the current element context.